# C++ enums into templated function

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have an enum class and I have this bunch of very similar code that converts enum into templated function call:

```cpp
auto func1(Type type, ...params)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case Type::typeA: return func1<Type::typeA>(params);
    case Type::typeB: return func1<Type::typeB>(params);
    case Type::typeC: return func1<Type::typeC>(params);
    ...
    }
}

auto func2(Type type, ...params)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case Type::typeA: return func2<Type::typeA>(params);
    case Type::typeB: return func2<Type::typeB>(params);
    case Type::typeC: return func2<Type::typeC>(params);
    ...
    }
}

// more such func3, func4, ...
```

I can generate this code with `#define` macros. Can I do anything with templates?
I can create a template class per each enum type, each class containing all functions.
But how to call that function by name?

Comment: Show the macro solution to make more clear what you need. Also give more explanation of what you need. If the shown code is relevant for your question, then make a clean [mre] instead of something with multiple `...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Params>
auto visit(Func func, Type type, Params&&... params)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case Type::typeA:
        return func(std::integral_constant<Type, Type::typeA>{}, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    case Type::typeB:
        return func(std::integral_constant<Type, Type::typeB>{}, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    case Type::typeC:
        return func(std::integral_constant<Type, Type::typeC>{}, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    //...
    }
}
```

With call similar to:

```
visit([](auto t, int e){ return Func1<t()>(e); }, type, 42);
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3bfe3642042d6f5)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `func1/2/3` as a template template parameter and forward the call to that.

```
typename <template <typename> typename Func, typename... Params>
auto switchFunction(Type type, Params&&... params) {
    switch (type)
    {
    case Type::typeA: return Func<Type::typeA>(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    case Type::typeB: return Func<Type::typeB>(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    case Type::typeC: return Func<Type::typeC>(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    ...
    }
}
```

Then you use that like so

```
auto someOtherFunc(Type type, int param1, double param2)
{
    return switchFunction<func1>(type, param1, param2);
}
```

For this to work, all versions of `func1` has to return the same type.

Additionally all the calls to `func1` needs to be valid. Not just the one that is selected by the switch.

Comment: OP has also to transform template functions in template classes.